# plot function: how to add a formula as an axis tick-label?

Tags: matlab, plot, formula, symbols

Consider having:

```
figure
xlabel('\rho_t')
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{-3,-2,-1,'\rho_t',1,2,3})
```

As you can see, Matlab only recongnises `\rho_t` inside `xlabel()` command as a symbol. How do you make MATLAB see `\rho_t` in `set()` as a symbol too?

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you can't. See for more details - http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/104522-xticklabel-and-latex-still-not-supported. As suggested in that thread, you can use commands like `text` to replace the ticks, and http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8722-rotate-tick-label will just do it for you.

Comment: I have answered a similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24913010/adding-text-to-y-axis-matlab/24930011#24930011